# how can i retrive the magic value from a _IOW macro generated ioctl number

Tags: linux-device-driver, ioctl

I'm relatively new to linux drivers and am facing an issue in setting up ioctl numbers. I have a character driver where I've implemented an ioctl that can be called from a user application. Currently, I've trying to implement the ioctl as a generic wrapper. I need to retrieve the 'magic number' from the ioctl number.

> `#define DEV1_MAGIC  'L'`
>   `#define DEV1_MAGIC  'k'`
>   `#define ADD_DEVICE1 _IOW(DEV1_MAGIC, 1, int)`
>   `#define ADD_DEVICE2 _IOW(DEV1_MAGIC, 2, int)`

I call the ioctl function from the user space application, which has the same definitions of the ioctl numbers as the character drivers.

> `ioctl(fd_dev, ADD_DEVICE1, &arg);`

In the ioctl function i would like to retrieve the `DEV1_MAGIC` value from the `ADD_DEVICE1` ioctl number argument to the ioctl function.

Is there a pre-defined function that can do this for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `((cmd & _IOC_TYPEMASK) >> _IOC_TYPESHIFT)`

Comment: thanks, found out that the ioctl number is made up of 4 parts, 'direction', 'size', 'type',  and 'number'.     
IOCTL number = direction << 30 | size << 16 | type << 8 | number.

Comment: I haven't yet come across and example with 'direction' specified when setting the ioctl number. What is the 'direction' field for?

Comment: Typically, the 'direction' specifies how memory pointed to by the final argument of the ioctl is handled. For example, if the ioctl only reads from the argument memory, it is defined using `_IOW(...)`, and if the ioctl only writes to the argument memory, it is defined using `_IOR(...)`. This is possibly opposite to what you might expect since it is from the point of view of the user code writing something to or reading something from the device. There are also `_IOWR(...)` and `_IO(...)`.

Comment: And rather than `((cmd & _IOC_TYPEMASK) >> _IOC_TYPESHIFT)`, you can use `_IOC_TYPE(cmd)` to decode the magic type value. I'm not sure why I missed that earlier!